# How to read a Gallio Report

Tags: report, gallio

I'm trying to read or redirect the test console output. I'm doing an AssertAreEqualIgnoringOrder and I need to parse some of the values within the failures. The failures output looks like this:

Expected elements to be equal but possibly in a different order.
       Ensure the list of idols matches with the db

```
   Equal Elements   : ["98932", "670945", "6747749", "6770804", "7110604", "13280109", "13280121", "13280149", "14448042", "14448336", "15726213", "17009409", "17245584", "93123", "2212314", "10129661", "13280123", "13280125", "13280135", "13280144", "17245263", "18784003", "1112597", "2885514", "8505390", "13279857", "15032800", "17009391", "17009396", "17009398", "17880635", "18340462", "3606775", "13280116", "13280133", "13280137", "14448341", "15050039", "16711731", "17008920", "17009377", "17009381", "17009402", "17245606", "17901335", "865871", "6029748", "17009372", "17009386", "17009406", "17245604", "19113286", "19865372"]
   Excess Elements  : ["14419207"]
   Missing Elements : ["17241620"]
```

How can I read this directly or redirect it to a file? If I can just parse the output, I can work it afterwards with some RegEx, that will not be a problem.

Another solution would be to parse the Gallio report file, but I'm sure there is a faster way.

Can you help me, please?

Thanks,
Andrei